# Custom "select files" button not working as expected

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I am implementing fine uploader. Here's what I have done:

1) I have added the following html and js classes:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fineuploader-3.4.1.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Document Type" data-bind="value: type"/>
                                   <div id="fine-uploader-basic" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click:$root.uploadFile">
                                        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Click to upload
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="messages"></div>
```

**JS File**

```
uploadFile: function(data) { 
       var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: "php/fileupload.php"
        }
    });
    }
```

**fineupload.php file:**

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['qqfile'];
$uploadDirectory = 'uploads';
$target = $uploadDirectory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file['files.php'];
$result = null;
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $result = array('success'=> true);
    $result['uploadName'] = $file['name'];
} else {
    $result = array('error'=> 'Upload failed');
}
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

**files.php ( where the files are stored)**

```
<?php 

// Include the uploader class
require_once 'php/fileupload.php';

$uploader = new qqFileUploader();

// Specify the list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$uploader->allowedExtensions = array();

// Specify max file size in bytes.
$uploader->sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

// Specify the input name set in the javascript.
$uploader->inputName = 'qqfile';

// If you want to use resume feature for uploader, specify the folder to save parts.
$uploader->chunksFolder = 'chunks';

// Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
$result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads');

// To save the upload with a specified name, set the second parameter.
// $result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads/', md5(mt_rand()).'_'.$uploader->getName());

// To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
$result['uploadName'] = $uploader->getUploadName();

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**Issues:**

When I click the button, it changes to the following: 
[image]

That red button inside the green one should be separate from the green button.

And also, the popup for choosing a file does not appear. Both PHP files have 777 permission.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file is irrelevant as far as this particular problem is concerned.  If you don't want to use Fine Uploader's default styled "select files" button, you must point Fine Uploader at your custom "button" element.

In your case, you'd need to add a `button` option like this:
`button: document.getElementById('#fine-uploader-basic')`

Comment: When you say that my php is irrevelant, which php file are you talking about? Also, which part of the file is irrelevant?

Comment: I meant there is no need to discuss PHP files since your problem is strictly client-side.